# Bulk action via MySQL query: render all posts in category private

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I want to do a bulk action on WordPress posts from a specific category: 
I want to render all posts in the category private.

This MySQL query seems close, but it isn't working 
(I think I'm getting the parenthetical point wrong):

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status= 'private' WHERE post_staus = 'publish' and ID in (select object_id from wp_term_relationships where term_taxonomy_id  = 25);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have an error in "WHERE **post_staus**": should be "WHERE **post_status**".

Comment: actually, UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status= 'private' WHERE post_staus = 'publish' works fine. The problem seems to be with the parentheses. Maybe the "select" isn't needed

Comment: I'm sorry to insist, but if you run that query as you wrote it on an **unaltered** Wordpress database, you'll get this error : #1054 - Unknown column 'post_staus' in 'where clause'

Comment: The parentheses are ok (and needed), as is the select subquery.